# Use the intermediate value theorem to prove the following equations have solution.

Tags: calculus, limits

a) $$\ e^x = 2 - x^2$$
b) $$\ \sin(x) = x^2 - 1$$

The intermediate value theorem says if $F$ is a continues function in a closed interval $[A,B]$, and you choose a value $K$ between $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ where $f(A) ≠ f(B)$, Then, there is a value between $A$ and $B$, $C$, such that $f(C) = K$.

I tried to solve the first one by trying to do what the intermediate value theorem says. Then I went on by choosing 2 values A and B. But the first equation has a weird behavior and so does the second one.

Their graphs have 2 long vertical lines with a medium space between them, and Choosing values to plug in doesn't return exact numbers, I'm confused, if anyone can give more clarifications about these problems it would be of great help for me.

Comment: Hint (for $a$):  Let $f(x)=e^x+x^2-2$.  What is $f(0)$?  What is $f(1)$?  For $b$..what does "sen" mean?

Comment: What is $sen(x)$?

Comment: "*Their graphs have 2 long vertical lines with medium space between them*"... I do not know what you tried to graph.  Did you try to graph $e^x=2-x^2$... which has nothing to do with $y$ at all?  You should have graphed the one function $y=e^x$ and graph the other function $y=2-x^2$ on top of that one to see the intersection [like so](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3De%5Ex,+y%3D2-x%5E2).

Comment: @cat The asker is likely from a Spanish- or Portuguese-speaking country. $\mathrm{sen}(x)\equiv \sin(x)$

Comment: @MichaelLee thanks, I already fixed

Comment: @JMoravitz I used a program to graph these equations, I think it did it wrong then.

Comment: In any case, if you can show that the left side is smaller at some point than the right and is larger at some other point than the right and that both sides are continuous, then the theorem says there must be a point where they are actually equal.  As for choosing what values to plug in, it would be convenient to pick inputs which *would* yield convenient exact results, e.g. $0,1,\pi$.  What is $\sin(0)$?  What is $\sin(\pi)$?  What is $0^2-1$?  What is $\pi^2-1$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, I got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint for the first**

Let $f (x)=e^x-2+x^2$.

- $f $ is continuous at $[0,1] $
- $f (0)=-1<0$
- $f (1)=e-1>0$
- $0\in (f (0),f (1)) $

hence there exist $c\in (0,1) $ such that
$f (c)=0$ or
$$e^c=2-c^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, is this e the euler's number ?, and to solve the second one I should use the values in radians ?

Comment: @hjx You can take zero and pi.

Comment: Clear up something, Why did you passed e^k to the right hand side as positive and 2 got negative ?

Comment: @hjx note:  $e^x=2-x^2$ iff $e^x\color{red}{+x^2-2}=2-x^2\color{red}{+x^2-2}$ iff $e^x+x^2-2=0$.  We can add and subtract the same thing to both sides without changing the truth of the statement

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks one more time,You are the man.

Answer (score 0):

Showing that $e^x = 2 - x^2$ has a solution is the same as showing the function $f(x) = e^x - 2 + x^2$ has a zero. Use the intermediate value theorem on $f(x)$ (note $f(x)$ is continuous).

Comment: thanks for the help.